# Как добавить файл шрифта в сборку на auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe, dearpygui

Пишу приложение на `dearpygui`, там есть место, где я подключаю кастомный шрифт для поддержки кириллицы. В коде это выглядит так:

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("./LiteralRegular.otf", 18, default_font=True, tag="Default font") as f:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
```

Разумеется, в папке с проектом лежит тот самый `LiteralRegular.otf`

```
- main.py
- LiteralRegular.otf
```

Все корректно работает при запуске из VSCode или PyCharm, но когда я собрал всё в .exe через   `auto-py-to-exe`, при запуске программы получаю ошибку:

```
Exception: Error: [1000] Message:   Font file could not be found
```

Я пробовал перезапускать сборку, указывая файл шрифта дополнительным файлом, но результат такой же. Подскажите, как решить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы запаковываете сам шрифт в `.exe` или потом его рядом с `.exe` кладете? Если второе, то попробуйте просто указать `"LiteralRegular.otf"` без `./`

Можно запаковать папку со шрифтом в `.exe` и попробовать получить к нему путь вот таким способом:

```
# Получаем путь к текущей директории, где находится исполняемый файл
current_directory = sys._MEIPASS if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS') else os.getcwd()
folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'font')
font_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
```

Comment: По вашей подсказке не стал упаковывать шрифт вместе с программой, а просто переложил её вручную. Так сработало (Путь указал без ./). Спасибо