Как использовать собственный файл шрифта в tkinter, чтобы он отображался на любом пк
У меня есть файл со шрифтом "GloriaHallelujah-Regular.ttf". Для конвертации в .exe файл я использую pyinstaller.
Если установить этот шрифт, то им можно пользоваться из программы следующим образом:
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

gloria = font.Font(family='Gloria Hallelujah', size=64)

Но нужно, чтобы шрифт отображался на любом пк, даже если он на нём заранее не установлен, при запуске программы .exe
Я смотрел подобные вопросы, там был примерно такой код, но он по каким-то причинам отказывается работать (шрифт не отображается, даже при запуске до конвертации в .exe)
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

gloria_path = resource_path('GloriaHallelujah-Regular.ttf')
gloria = tkfont.Font(family=gloria_path, size=64)


Вы файл шрифта запаковывали в .exe ?

Да, при использовании pyinstaller, я добавлял шрифт в дополнительные файлы, но не помогло.
Но до данного этапа я ещё не дошёл - у меня не получается использовать файл шрифта, чтобы загрузить оттуда шрифт во время выполнения программы. Запаковать в .exe - это второй этап


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1563585/562052 2) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1552478/562052 посмотрите тут. Так же покажите какой командой собирали свой .exe


Я не дохожу до создания .exe, проблема возникает даже при обычном запуске в idle (.py файла).
gloria_path = resource_path('GloriaHallelujah-Regular.ttf')
gloria = tkfont.Font(family=gloria_path, size=64)
Когда я запускаю код, если попытаться получить атрибуты gloria при помощи gloria.actual(), то результатом становится {'family': 'Arial', 'size': 64, ...}
Значение family явно не соответствует ожиданию. Файл .py и файл шрифта находятся в одной директории
